# Error al hacer una operación matemática con Hilos en C# Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, hilos

Estoy intentando realizar una operación matemática de multiplicación a través de una Interfaz creada en forms, en esta solo leeré el valor que se agrega que será el que se multiplica de 0 a 9 para así obtener su tabla de multiplicar la cual voy a guardar en un textbox multilínea.

**El problema es que...** al momento de ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'Tabla1' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente

```
public void op1 ()
        { int Multiplicador = Convert.ToInt32(ESPACIO1.Text);
            string accion = "";
            string almacen = "";
            int conteo = 0;
            Thread OP1 = new Thread(Operacion2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                conteo = i;
            almacen = accion;
            accion = almacen + Multiplicador + " x " + conteo + "= " + Multiplicador * conteo + ", ";
            string guardaditoazteca = Tabla1.Text;
            Tabla1.Text =guardaditoazteca  + accion;
            return;
        }
        private void BOTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread Hilo = new Thread(new ThreadStart(op1));
            Hilo.Start(); 
            
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No podes modificar la pantalla desde un thread. Tu thread debe ejecutar un evento que sea obtenido por el proceso principal para poder hacer un invoke a si mismo y llegar al proceso padre...

Comment: Hola gbianchio disculpa las molestias pero me podrías explicar un poco mas sobre esto. es mi primera vez realizando un hilo.

Comment: La verdad que yo no. Tendria que ponerme a investigar porque lo he hecho pero en wpf... y no se si sea igual en winforms....asi que te toca investigar a ti...

Comment: Para que querrias pasar una multiplicacion a un Hilo? Segundo lo mas usado hoy en dia son las Task, que tambien trabaja en hilos separados pero con la clase Task